# Fractional constraint to convex constraint

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am looking for solution of the following:
Is it possible to rewrite constraint

$\frac{a^T x}{c^T x + d} \leq K$,

where $x$ is vector variable and $K$ is scalar variable as well

as a convex constraint, i.e so it doesn't contain any multiplications.
So far my considerations are that function on the left is quasiconvex(rational linear function), therefore it is possible to make a level set on it. However, the current form of the constraint is not implementable. Most likely that I have to think out about substitution, but can't work it out so far. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know anything about whether $K$ and $c^{T}x+d$ are positive?

Comment: Yes, both $K$ and $c^T x +d$ are positive

Comment: Then why don't you multiply both sides by $c^T x+d$?

Comment: Because K is a variable, so that on the right side we will have $K(c^T x + d)$, so it is multiplication of the variables.

Comment: You either have multiplication of variables or division of variables. Generally you can't scape both

Comment: @polfosol There are some cases when linear fractional programming can be formulated in linear form by doing substitution and introducing new variable. I am wondering if similar can be done to the problem above?

Comment: By _generally_ I meant that there is no general way. As you stated, in _some_ cases there are some tricks. But since you gave no more details about your problem, nothing more can be said

Comment: @polfosol Well, I told that my denominator and variable on the RHS are positive. Maybe you can ask me if there is any detail that should be there so that some tricks may be applied?

Comment: Could you show the entire problem, because it may have some structure you can exploit.

Comment: I would suggest you're not asking the right question. The question isn't whether or not you can manipulate this constraint into a form that is acceptable to some convex solver. The question is: *does this constraint describe a convex set in $(x,K)$. That's a matter of geometry. If it does, then yes, there's bound to be a way to rewrite it. If not, then no amount of rewriting will fix that.

Comment: Dear @MichaelGrant, I already told you my opinion about convexity of that constraint. I can repeat thought, and you can confirm it, since you have much more knowledge about convex optimization than me. So since the LHS is linear fraction function, it is a quasiconvex function. It means that when you make a level set, the set is convex(according to cvx book by Boyd). So my problem fits this statement perfectly, as my problem is level set on the quasiconvex function. The only problem is that RHS is a variable but not a constant. Hence, I'm looking for reformulation that satisfies DCP rules.

Comment: "The only problem" is the _critical_ problem. Everything you said about quasiconvexity is irrelevant, precisely because $K$ is not constant.

Comment: So again, trying to satisfy the DCP rules is putting the cart before the horse. You need to prove it's _convex_ before you bother with DCP construction, and I am in no way optimistic that is possible here.